# Bridging header does not exits. Error show different path than in build settings

Tags: xcode, git, swift

I imported my project from Git and got an error when trying to compile the application

The error console states 
`Bridging header '/Users/differentUser/Documents/Projects/QA/Bridging-Header.h' does not exist`

Where it is actually located at:

`Bridging header '/Users/actualUser/Documents/Projects/QA/Bridging-Header.h' does not exist`

the actual location is listed in the build setting as well under the **Objective-C Bridging Header**

Any guidance is appreciated. I've tried deleting the file and creating another, changing the name, ect

but it all ends up with the same error and path in the Error Log

Comment: "Where it is actually located at: Bridging header '/Users/actualUser/Documents/Projects/QA/Bridging-Header.h' does not exist" Huh?

Comment: [Check out this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24005242/2108547)